# how to fill a set in C++ with input from user

Tags: c++, set, cin

how can we fill a set in C++ from user input in one liner
I know we can store input in a variable and then use
set.insert(some_variable)

but cant we take input from user directly?
like set.insert(cin>>set[i])?

I am just a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the values into a `std::set` with `std::copy_n`. (Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n))

The source will be the `std::istream_iterator` ([described here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)) and the destination will be the `std::inserter` wrapper ([described here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter)).

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    // Our set
    std::set<int> s{};

    // How many values do we want to read
    const size_t numberOfUserInputs{ 3 };

    // Copy values from std::cin to set
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), numberOfUserInputs, std::inserter(s, s.begin()));

    // Debug output
    for (int i : s) std::cout << i << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't do this.
things that go with `vector` like

```cpp
    std::vector<int> he;
    auto endf = he.end();
    *he.insert(endf, 1) = 5;
```

will not go with `set`. `insert` returns const_iterator.